# PHP script to download file not working in IE

Tags: php, http-headers

I have a script that takes a key from $_GET['key'] , looks up the location in a database and uses the readfile together with some headers to present a download for the use. This works in Firefox but not IE8, haven't been able to test it on another IE. I get the following error in IE: "Internet Explorer cannot download download.php from www.example.com". As if it is trying to download the PHP script.

```
$the_query = "SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `user_id`=" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . " AND `key`='" . $key . "'";

$result = mysql_query($the_query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$file = '/var/www/vhosts/www.example.com/httpsdocs/uploads/' . $row['id'] . '/' . $row['file'];

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-length: ".filesize($file));
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Cache-control: private");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . rawurlencode(basename($file)));
readfile($file);
```

Comment: take a look at SQL injection and mysql_real_escape_string. This piece of code is vulnerable.

Comment: Oh lord yes please use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Don't know much about this, but it may have something to do with the file extension in $file

Comment: If you mean on the $key variable then yes I am using it already, just not in the code above.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To solve the error : "Internet Explorer cannot download download.php from www.example.com",
Add these headers to your script:

`header("Pragma: ");`

`header("Cache-Control: ");`

The code will remove the Cache-Control from headers which makes the download problem.

The above code should be added at the top of the file.

It works fine for us.

Comment: Thanks a Million for saving my life from Alien Bugs coming from Planet mars... I never knew what I can do but your this armor of yours helped me in killing this VERY VERY BIG BUG... Bug is dead... YAY!!.. Thanks :-)

Comment: We went round and round with this problem. tried so many recommendations from blog posts etc. This was the one that fixed it!

Answer (score 10):

Managed to get this working by using the first example from php.net

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:
`header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");`
with this:
`header("Content-Type: application/force-download");`

According to this [post](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=70959), IE doesn't normally listen to your headers, and instead looks for itself what you are sending.

Comment: I already tried this before, same error unfortunately, thanks.

Comment: `application/octet-stream` is the official MIME media type for data that is intended to be downloaded (see RFC 2046).

Answer (score 1):

Set the Content-Disposition header to "attachment", like so (in PHP): where attachment was scripted.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
```

And add the following in .htaccess and add what ever extension that you want to download not only txt

```
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|pdf|csv|xls|xlsx|xlam|xlsb|xlsm|msg|doc|docx|mpg|jpg|png)">
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, if someone (like me) is facing problems with directly entering a filedownload into the address bar using a secured https-request. There is a IE bug that is causing this download to fail:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308/en-us

Only workaround seems to be setting the cache-headers according to the article.

Answer (score 0):

Never replace this:
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

with this:
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");

"application/octet-stream" is simply the most universal and works on most browsers.

I tried using "application/zip" in one of my tests since I was technically dealing with a ZIP file, but IE6.0 corrupted the download! Everything else behaved normally though. But yeah, had to switch back to "application/octet-stream" so any code out there that tries to detect the file extension, and switch to other content-types specific to the extension are risky! You're better off using "application/octet-stream" for ALL binary files!