# PHP force download not working?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

On my HTML page I have made a JQuery ajax request to a php script that should force a download, but nothing is happening?

On my html page (in click event handler for a link)...

```
var file = "uploads/test.css";
$.ajax(
{
    type      : "POST",
    url       : "utils/Download_File.php",
    data      : {"file":file}
})
```

And the Download_File.php script looks like this

```
<?php

Download_File::download();

class Download_File
{
    public static function download()
    {
        $file = $_POST['file'];

        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
        readfile('http://localhost/myapp/' . $file);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

But nothing is happening for some reason? I looked at the response headers in firebug and cant see any problems. Im using Xampp. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not the way it's done. You need to set `location.href` to the file you want to download, or use an iframe. Check out this question:

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax File Download using Jquery, PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599670/ajax-file-download-using-jquery-php)

Answer (score 10):

You should specify the `Content-Transfer-Encoding`. Also, you should specify the `filename` on your `Content-Disposition`.

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
readfile('http://localhost/myapp/'.$file);
exit;
```

It's important to include double-quotes around the `filename` as this is required by [RFC 2231](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2231.txt). Firefox is known to have problems downloading files that have spaces in the file name if the `filename` is not in quotes.

Also, check to make sure there is no white space after your closing `?>`. If even a space exists after the closing PHP tag, the headers won't be sent to the browser.

As a side note, if you have a number of common file types you're going to offer for download, you might consider specifying those MIME types. This provides a better experience for the end user. For example, you could do something like this:

```
//Handles the MIME type of common files
$extension = explode('.', $file);
$extension = $extension[count($extension)-1];
SWITCH($extension) {
  case 'dmg':
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    break;
  case 'exe':
    header('Content-Type: application/exe');
    break;
  case 'pdf':
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    break;
  case 'sit':
    header('Content-Type: application/x-stuffit');
    break;
  case 'zip':
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    break;
  default:
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    break;
}
```

Comment: @Parris Could you share any info on this? I have a download script that does some similar stuff (using cURL instead of `readfile`) and if there's a potential problem, I'd like to address it in my code. :)

Comment: Yea checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218925/php-script-to-download-file-not-working-in-ie

It identifies the issue, and attempts to solve it. There are also issues around trying to download from https and you are in http...

Comment: "Firefox is known to have problems downloading files that have spaces in the file name if the filename is not in quotes." Not just Firefox, either.  The command-line wget tool (for Linux/BSD/OSX) is extremely touchy, to the point where you cannot download from VBulletin forum software with the correct filenames.

Answer (score -1):

Use `document.location.href=URL`, instead of ajax..

In my experience ajax causes the problem (download does not work, print contents of the file on browser console).