# File Download inside iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, download

I'm using following method to download a file.on a button click inside a **iframe**.it's working fine in every browser except IE.can some one plz suggest me a sollution

```
private void DownloadToBrowser(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
            Context.Response.Clear();

            Context.Response.ClearHeaders();

            Context.Response.ClearContent();

            Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);

            Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

            Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            Context.Response.Flush();

            Context.Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

            Context.Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing the `Context.Response.Flush();` line... I don't think it's necessary (as it will happen as part of `Context.Response.End();` line), and maybe messing up how the browser receives the file on the next line.

Also, is the file you're transmitting definitely a plain-text file?  If not, you'll need to provide a different `Context.Response.ContentType();`

Answer (score 0):

You have most probably missed some HTTP response headers required by IE.

There is [KB on microsoft web](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519).

Also take a look at similar question on SO : [PHP script to download file not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218925/php-script-to-download-file-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
Context.Response.Buffer = true;
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName );
Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(dataBytes ,0,FileContentLength);
```

Also try adding this to your aspx page :

```
<%@ Page aspCompat="True" other attributes %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Understanding I m using Dataset,
For download as a Excel File

Use Namespace:

```
        using System.IO;
        using System.Data;   

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Table");
        ds.Tables.Add("Table1");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Field1");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Field2");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Field3");
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add();
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] = "1";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1] = "2";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2] = "3";


        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        // first let's clean up the response.object
        response.Clear();
        response.Charset = "";

        // set the response mime type for excel
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.xls");

        // create a string writer
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                // instantiate a datagrid
                DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
                dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                dg.DataBind();
                dg.RenderControl(htw);
                response.Write(sw.ToString());
                response.End();
            }
        }
```

For Download as a Word File

Replace

```
        response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.doc");
```