# Displaying or downloading Word, PDF documents etc in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: php, http-headers, content-type, content-disposition

I am grabbing various documents (PDF, DOCX etc) from an Oracle BLOB and trying to display them for the user, here's a sample of the code I'm using:

```
// $p_terms is the document from the Oracle blob
// $p_doc_name is the document name
// $p_doc_type is the document MIME type

while(!$p_terms->eof()){
    $var .=$p_terms->read($p_terms->size());
}

header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$p_doc_name.'"');
header('Content-Type: "'.$doc_type.'"');

echo $var;
```

In **Firefox** I get this:

[image]

And in **Chrome** I get this:

[image]

**But in Internet Explorer 8, nothing happens.** No download dialog at all, it just displays a progress bar for a few seconds but stays on the page.

Many thanks

**Update:** Many thanks to user1666456 for suggesting `Content-Disposition: attachment` - this is great progress as IE actually attempts to download the file, but it then produces a number of dialog boxes in Word, for example https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcWwg.png

Comment: Maybe trying `Content-Disposition: attachment`?

Comment: That's a great shout, thank you! Unfortunately though I then get this error whilst trying to open it... though it does open just fine after clicking through a few dialog boxes! http://i.imgur.com/jx7wjjM.png

Comment: Which `Content-Type` do you use? Maybe try `application/octet-stream`. Another problem [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#81045)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218925/php-script-to-download-file-not-working-in-ie